# Webpage redirecting before vertx eventbus opening

Tags: javascript, websocket, vert.x

I binded a javascript function to a hyperlink, the function consists of opening a vertx eventbus and sending the message. The problem I am facing is the page is getting re-directed before the vertx eventbus is opening and sending the message.

On console:
WebSocket connection to 'ws://XXX/websocket' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.

I cannot stop the redirection until bus is opened and message is sent, as I should not effect the user experience. So is there any way to achieve this asynchronously.

Comment: I think you'll need to provide a minimal example

Comment: Are you sure you're handling the nonblocking calls correctly?